# How: windows remotely connects to ubuntu?

Tags: remote, nx

How should I use no machine in windows to remotely connect to ubuntu12.04? I got this:

> Authentication failed.

Do I need to configure something in Ubuntu machine?

In Ubuntu machine, I chose '**sharing**' in Remote Desktop Preferences.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu's Desktop Sharing is just the VNC protocol under the hood, whereas Windows uses RDP.  So you're either going to have to get Ubuntu running RDP.  As @laurent mentioned, there's xrdp, but I haven't used it personally.  The easier method is to use a VNC client on Windows, and there are a tonne of those that should all work, including:

- [TightVNC](http://tightvnc.com/)
- [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/)

There's also the NoMachine/NX stuff, but it's moderately complicated to get set up compared to VNC-based stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu you need to install and configure at least `nx server` and `nx node`. Not sure if you need to install `nx client` too. You can download them from no machine website.

Another option is to install `xrdp`package in ubuntu and to connect using the normal RDP connection software in Windows.

The sharing desktop option is to share to another Ubuntu desktop using the Ubuntu's Sharing Desktop Application.

Comment: I am trying to use xrdp to connect to the existing NX server, and it seems to connect OK, however, I have no status bar or no menu bar on the left. What would be my best solution on this ?

Comment: xrdp should be the server on the ubuntu machine and you connect to it using a RDP client (native windows RDP or possibly something like Remmina on Linux) and you don't need to use NX on any of the machines. If you use NX (client and server), afaik there was a problem with the Unity interface and you have to configure nx client for that. I'll try to find the link of this answer and report here quickly

Comment: Found it... NX client doesn't work with default config using Unity 3D so the link below shows how to fix that and a few other possibilities (running xfce or unity 2d - not sure this last one still works). http://superuser.com/questions/389992/freenx-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-11-10/390008#390008. Anyways I didn't try NX since some time as using xrdp and remmina (or windows native RDP client) is a lot easier and faster.